# リンクからhtmlを表示させる方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

いま映画情報のWEBサイトを作っています。
表示させてあるリンクから、show.html.erbを表示させたいです。
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#show
とエラーが出ました。
products_controller.rbに

```
class ProductsController < RankingController
  def index
    # productsテーブルから最新順に作品を２０件取得する
    @products = Product.limit(20).order('id DESC')
  end

  def shows
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def search
    # 検索フォームのキーワードをあいまい検索して、productsテーブルから20件の作品情報を取得する
    @products=Product.find(params[:title]).order('id DESC').limit(20)
    @products =Product.where("name like '%" +title+ "%'")
  end
end
```

このように記述しました。
それがshow.html.erbのa hrefに反映されるようにしたいです。
show.html.erbには

```
<div id="main_cnt_wrapper">
    <div id="yjContentsBody">
      <div class="yjContainer">
        <span class="yjGuid"><a id="yjContentsStart" name="yjContentsStart"></a><img alt="ここから本文です" height="1" src="http://i.yimg.jp/yui/jp/tmpl/1.1.0/audionav.gif" width="1"></span>
        <div id="yjMain">
          <article class="section">
            <div class="container">
              <header class="header header--section">
                <h2 class="text-middle">
                  <i class="icon-movie color-gray-light"></i><%= @product.title %>
                </h2>
              </header>
              <p style="text-align: center">
                <img src="<%= @product.image_url %>" alt="<%= @product.title %>">
              </p>
              <div style="text-align: right">
                <a href="/show/:id">この作品を投稿する</a>　←ここが重要
              </div>
              <header class="header header--section">
                <h2 class="text-middle">
                  <i class="icon-movie color-gray-light"></i>みんなのレビュー
                </h2>
              </header>
              <ul style="padding: 0">
                <li style="border-bottom: dotted 1px">
                  <div class="thumbnail__caption">
                    <h3 class="text-xsmall text-overflow" title="テスト太郎">
                      </span>テスト太郎<small 2014=""></small>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="text-small">
                      <span class="rating-star"><i class="star-actived rate-[ここに評価を表示]0"></i></span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      面白い！
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div id="yjSub">
```

と記述しました。

Answer (score -1):

あんまり自信がないですが

```
  @products=Product.find(params[:title]).order('id DESC').limit(20)
```

だと、id で検索する事になるんじゃないですかね?

```
  @products=Product.find_by_title(params[:title]).order('id DESC').limit(20)
```

とかじゃないかと思います。

あと

```
def search
  @products=Product.find(params[:title]).order('id DESC').limit(20)
  @products =Product.where("name like '%" + title + "%'")
end
```

だと @products に2回代入しているので、
どっちかいらない気がします。

それと、params に変な文字が入ってないかチェックしないとダメだと思います。
お客さんの個人情報とか入ってなかったら、
盗まれたり壊されたりしてもいいのかもしれませんが

気になる場合は、`strong parameters`,`rails プレースホルダー`,`SQLインジェクション` で検索して下さい。

Comment: Strong paramatersはパラメータの存在は検証しますがその値は検証しません。

Comment: そうみたいですね。少し追記してみました。

Comment: うーん。Railsにおけるvalidationはモデルの責務なので、こういう場面に使える仕組みは標準ではないです。セキュリティ上の観点で質問のコードがまずいのはプレースホルダを使ってないことで、プレースホルダ使っていれば「変な文字が入っていないかチェック」する必要は無いです。「体系的に学ぶ 安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方」(ISBN 4797361190)という書籍を参考に紹介しておきます。

Comment: validation は僕が CodeIgniter のフォームバリデーション っていうものと勘違いしてますね。
「まず、自分がよく調べましょう」ですね。
あまり便利なものを使ってなかったので、全部手動でクォートする考えになっている気がします。
問題なのは、where の部分で自分で文字列を結合している部分ですね。
find の方も問題ありだと思っていました。こっちは多分うまくやってくれますよね。
そうしない理由が、速度以外になさそうな気がするので。

Comment: 十分か分からないですが、検索キーワードを3つ上げてみました。validation については消しました。